# Properties involving other variables

Tags: c#, properties

How do I fix this?
City is another property/variable in my project.
Product Total is as well.
I am trying to get differing sales tax calculations based on where the sale has occurred.

```
public double SalesTax  // Define result property
{
  get
  {
    if (City == "Town #1")
      return Math.Round(this.ProductTotal * #1_TAX_RATE, 2);
    else if (City == "Town #2")
      return Math.Round(this.ProductTotal * #2_TAX_RATE, 2);
    else if (City == "Town #3")
      return Math.Round(this.ProductTotal * #3_TAX_RATE, 2);
    else if (City == "Town #4")
      return Math.Round(this.ProductTotal * #4_TAX_RATE, 2);
  }
  set
  {
    if ((value >= 0) && (value <= 1000.0))
      this.SalesTax = value;
    else
      ProcessError(String.Format("(0) can not be assigned to a SalesTax property", value));
  }
}
```

The error as pointed out is the get doesn't return a value and I do not understand why?

Comment: I guess the error is due to `get` not returning any thing for default case.

Comment: A `get` must return a value. In your code, what if City is `Town #5`, there is no `if` case for that and you code can't return a value for `SalesTax`. Hence the error

Comment: There is also an error in the setter. You are assigning `this.SalesTax`, this will invoke the setter again. You probably will see a stack overflow exception.

Comment: So I took out the last {else if}  and changed it to {else} only statement and it will default to City #4 now. Its not exactly what I wanted but I guess it has to default to something?

Answer (score 1):

This Property should probably be read-only, you also need to return something if 
City = something else

```
public double SalesTax  // Define result property
{
  get
  {
    int saleRate = 1;
    if (City == "Town #1")
      saleRate = #1_TAX_RATE;
    else if (City == "Town #2")
      saleRate = #2_TAX_RATE;
    else if (City == "Town #3")
      saleRate = #3_TAX_RATE;
    else if (City == "Town #4")
      saleRate = #4_TAX_RATE;

    return Math.Round(this.ProductTotal * saleRate, 2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your get:

```
get
  {
    switch(City)
    {
       case "Town #1":
            return Math.Round(this.ProductTotal * #1_TAX_RATE, 2);
       break;

      case "Town #2":
           return Math.Round(this.ProductTotal * #2_TAX_RATE, 2);
       break;

      case "Town #3":
           return Math.Round(this.ProductTotal * #3_TAX_RATE, 2);
       break;

     case "Town #4":
           return Math.Round(this.ProductTotal * #4_TAX_RATE, 2);
       break;

     case default:
           //default return value
       break;
    }
```